# how to only insert an as many items are in my array with php to mysql from json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

I have a php file that i am inserting data from a json into a mysql database, and i am using a foreach() to list the tech's and then insert them into mysql. my problem is it seems to just insert 3 of the same things into the database and not 1 for each tech.

Example

```
id 1, 1, 1
name mike, mike, mike
number 10, 10, 10

the above should be more like 

id 1, 2, 3
name mike, sandy, joe
number 10, 11, 12
```

I can see what i am trying to do but when i google i get nothing but how to count with count().

```
$ijobid = $data['invoice']['jobId'];
    foreach($data['jobAssignments'] as $chunk){
        $jatech = $chunk['technician'];
        $jatechid = $jatech['id'];
        $jatechname = $jatech['name'];
        $jasplit = $chunk['split'];
        $jadriving = $chunk['totalDrivingHours'];
        $jaworking = $chunk['totalWorkingHours'];
        $jaassigned = $chunk['assignedOn'];
        $jatechstatus = $chunk['status'];
        $jatechfinished = array($jatechid, $jatechname);
        $jobassignreults[] = $jatechfinished;
    }
    foreach($jatech as $key => $techs){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `techtable` (`ijobid`,`jtid`,`jtname`) VALUES ('$ijobid', '$jatechid', '$jatechname')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

}
```

this is my php code, i know it works to connect because i get data but it doesn't seem to work correctly. the tech data in the json is not static and can be different every time i pass it, so today it could list 1 tech tomorrow 5.

Thank you in advance.

Edit - here is the json section i am pulling from:

```
"jobAssignments": [
    {
      "id": 15797,
      "jobId": 15792,
      "jobNumber": "15792",
      "technician": {
        "id": 156,
        "name": "Mike"
      },
      "split": 100,
      "totalDrivingHours": 1680,
      "totalWorkingHours": 7680,
      "assignedOn": "2015-11-05T09:08:22.5680879",
      "status": "Done"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Please show the data as a JSON String or a PHP array `print_r($array)` So we can be sure what we are actually dealing with please

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added the tech section of the json that i am pulling from

Comment: Can you check that JSON it looks out of wak to me

Comment: @RiggsFolly how so? like it can only have 1 tech?

Comment: Is `ijobid` defined in the schema as unique or a auto increment column

Comment: Do you get an error message shown?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no error message just inserts the same tech and all his info 3 times

Comment: @RiggsFolly when i do discribe table i get this :ijobid
varchar(255)
NO
NULL

Comment: As you are in a situation where you want to run the same query more than once, it would be the perfect senario to use a parameterised query with bound variables so you prepare it once and execute it many times with different data. But thats not the reson for it not working

Comment: @RiggsFolly could it be that i need to some how count how many are in the tech chunk and then only pass the insert that many times? sorry i am new to nested information like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 foreach loops. The first consumes all the input data so leaving only the last occurance in the scalar variables. Your second foreach loops around `$jatech` which is the LAST version of `$jatech = $chunk['technician'];`

This should work a little better

```
$ijobid = $data['invoice']['jobId'];
foreach($data['jobAssignments'] as $chunk){
    $jatech = $chunk['technician'];
    $jatechid = $jatech['id'];
    $jatechname = $jatech['name'];
    $jasplit = $chunk['split'];
    $jadriving = $chunk['totalDrivingHours'];
    $jaworking = $chunk['totalWorkingHours'];
    $jaassigned = $chunk['assignedOn'];
    $jatechstatus = $chunk['status'];
    $jatechfinished = array($jatechid, $jatechname);
    $jobassignreults[] = $jatechfinished;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `techtable` (`ijobid`,`jtid`,`jtname`) 
                VALUES ('$ijobid', '$jatechid', '$jatechname')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

And this would be more efficient

```
$ijobid = $data['invoice']['jobId'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `techtable` (`ijobid`,`jtid`,`jtname`) 
                VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

foreach($data['jobAssignments'] as $chunk){
    $jatech = $chunk['technician'];
    $jatechid = $jatech['id'];
    $jatechname = $jatech['name'];
    $jasplit = $chunk['split'];
    $jadriving = $chunk['totalDrivingHours'];
    $jaworking = $chunk['totalWorkingHours'];
    $jaassigned = $chunk['assignedOn'];
    $jatechstatus = $chunk['status'];
    $jatechfinished = array($jatechid, $jatechname);
    $jobassignreults[] = $jatechfinished;

    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $ijobid, $jatechid, $jatechname);
    if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

The only thing you may need to check is that all 3 datatypes are in fact strings.

```
 $stmt->bind_param('sss', $ijobid, $jatechid, $jatechname);
```

Comment: so i should move the sql insert into the main foreach() and remove the 2nd for each?

Comment: Yes, basically, or use the parameterized prepared mechanism I suggested in version 2